# Difference in accessing member function via pointer of parent type or directly from derived class

Tags: c++

Consider three classes `A`, `B`, and `C`, where `A` is the parent of `B` and `C` with a function `A::doThing()`.

Is there any difference between the following two methods of calling `doThing()` in terms of performance (assuming `B` and `C` don't override `doThing()`?

```
B b1;
C c1;
A* a1 = &b1;
A* a2 = &c1;

//Option 1:
b1.doThing();
c1.doThing();

//Option 2:
a1->doThing();
a2->doThing();
```

In a tutorial app I saw they claimed that the second option was faster.  I understand that if B or C overrides `doThing()`, then the two different calls could have different results, but I don't get why the second way of calling the function would be faster? The direct quote (in the example they use option 2):

> We would have achieved the same result by calling the functions directly on the objects.  However, it's faster and more efficient to use pointers.

Edit:  Code from app as some have suggested I misunderstood:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Enemy {
    protected: 
        int attackPower;
    public:
        void setAttackPower(int a){
            attackPower = a;
        }
};

class Ninja: public Enemy {
    public:
        void attack() {
            cout << "Ninja! - "<<attackPower<<endl;
        }
};

class Monster: public Enemy {
    public:
        void attack() {
            cout << "Monster! - "<<attackPower<<endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    Ninja n;
    Monster m;
    Enemy *e1 = &n;
    Enemy *e2 = &m;

    e1->setAttackPower(20);
    e2->setAttackPower(80);

    n.attack();
    m.attack();
}
```

Comment: Can you refer me to the source of that quote.. I want to sue the writer for incompetency,

Comment: Is `doThing` `virtual` in this example?

Comment: I agree. You should stop using that source, whatever it is, for learning C++. That source fundamentally does not understand C++, and you deserve an upvote simply for recognizing potential idiocy, and innocently asking about it. Your instincts are right about where they should be.

Comment: No it's not `virtual`, it's implemented in `A` and `A` only.  And the source is Learn C++ an android app that I was using a while ago to bring me up to speed on syntax, but hasn't been very helpful for anything other than that.

Comment: Well, you might consider giving a review of that android app, mentioning that everyone on stackoverflow.com is LOLing at its pearls of wisdom.

Comment: Did the source really say, that the secobd option (and not the first) was faster?

Comment: @M.M fixed, was a typo.  The actual example had more verbose class names (`Enemy`, `Ninja`, `Monster`)

Comment: Maybe the app meant to talk about the case of a `virtual` function and was either unclear or you misunderstood. You say "override" but that is a moot point if the function is not virtual (non-virtual functions cannot be overridden)

Comment: @M.M posted the original code.

Comment: OK. I presume you are asking about the difference between `e1->setAttackPower(20)` and `n.setAttackPower(20)` ?

Comment: @M.M Yup, unless you can interpret the quote above the edit as referring to anything else?

Comment: OK. Conceptually `n.` has an extra conversion (`this` of `n` must be converted from `Ninja *` to `Enemy *`), however that conversion does not require any assembly instructions: in almost all cases both pointers have the same format and value, and even if they didn't, the compiler would substitute the value at compile-time

Comment: Any guide recommending `using namespace std` immediately goes into the "suspect" category (and should be attacked by ninjas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `doThing` is not `virtual`, it's all the same, as in all cases the exact method to call is resolved at compile time.

Otherwise:

- calling directly on the object should be always as fast as it gets, since the compiler is sure of the a actual type of the object, so there's no extra indirection step (no vtable lookup, possible inlining);
- when calling through pointer to base class, it's down to the ability of the compiler to prove the dynamic type of the object (or realizing that the method is never overridden); it everything is local to the function this may be easy, but otherwise it quickly gets difficult (for the compiler is not even trivial to understand that nobody is redefining a virtual method, because - barring LTCG and similar mechanisms - it has no knowledge of what happens in other translation units).

> We would have achieved the same result by calling the functions directly on the objects. However, it's faster and more efficient to use pointers.

If the context is as you reported, this is complete bullshit. Throw away whatever guide where found this, the author has no idea of what he is talking about.

Comment: If you want to be really pedantic, then there can be a difference is `B` or `C` define their own member functions `doThing`. Since `A::doThing` is not virtual, such definitions do not constitute overriding (as required by the OP), but the effect would be that `b1.doThing()` and `a->doThing()` call different functions.

Comment: @KerrekSB: sure, my "it's all the same" was actually referring just to the function call performance standpoint.